# onUnload AJAX Post to C# Back-end

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax

I'm limiting the amount of certain pop up windows with a static counter in the back-end of my web form application (C#). I only want to have 1 window open at a time. The back-end counter works fine, however when a user closes the child window I want to reset the counter in the back-end. For that I'm using AJAX with JS (can't use JQuery) and I'm calling that AJAX to make a POST in the back-end in an onUnload event.

I'm using IE 11.

Back-end method I want to call from my JavaScript.

```
public void DecreaseItem1()
{
    int? inspID = convert.ToInt(Request.QueryString["inspid"]);
    int? inpID_static = InspectionList.GetWindowInspID();
    string path = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath;
    if (path.Contains("ReadOnlyInspection"))
    {

        if (inspID != inpID_static)
        {
            InspectionList.DecreaseCounter();

        }
        else
        {
            InspectionList.DecreaseCounter();
            InspectionList.SetGetWindowInspID(null);
        }
    }
```

From my front-end I'm calling onUnload the DecreaseItem() JavaScript function.

Body tag

```
<body onUnload="DecreaseItem()" >
```

JavaScript function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">            

    function DecreaseItem() {
        var win_loc = "ReadOnlyInspection.aspx/DecreaseItem1";
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.open("POST", win_loc, true);
        xhttp.send();

     }   
</script>
```

[**problem**] Counter never gets decreased. Any help or suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does the actual call to back-end happen? If you had a break-point in back-end, would it be hit? Or can you see it Chrome console's network tab?

Comment: I can seee the request, but I can't use Chrome, so I open the developer tools in IE. However; the break-point in the backend is not hit...mainly because I'm closing the window?

Comment: And what response do you see in the request in IE? 
You should also be able to make a POST request to your website using Postman or similar app, and the break-point should get hit.